# AmChart percentage Clustered bar dynamic calculation

Tags: javascript, percentage, amcharts

I am trying to put a percent calculation in each column. How can I do this?

I have this for now:

```
var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
chart.addLegend(legend);

var qtd = 0;
var sum = 0;
for(i=0;i<datas.length;i++){
    sum[i] += Object.keys(datas[i]);
    qtd = (qtd < Object.keys(datas[i]).length - 1) ? Object.keys(datas[i]).length - 1 : qtd;
}
console.log(Object.keys(datas));
for(j=1;j<qtd+1;j++){
    datas[j].share = Math.round(datas[j].expenses / sum * 100);
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.valueField = "expenses"+(j);
    graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b> ([[share]]%)";
    graph.labelText = "[[share]]%";
    graph.labelPosition = "inside";
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.fillAlphas = 0.8;
    chart.addGraph(graph);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dayaners3/933t512e/

Comment: based on this example:
http://www.amcharts.com/tips/calculate-display-percent-value-columnbar/

Comment: So what percentage are you trying to calculate? Percentage of column's value within category/cluster? Percentage of column's value across all columns? Percentage of column's value for the same graph across all categories? You have to be specific what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i want calculate :
foreach 'Year' 
expenses1(2,3,...) / sum(expenses1+2+3+4) in 'year')

i dont if u can understand, sorry my english is very limited
i got this : https://jsfiddle.net/dayaners3/pxhqav7z/
but i calculate in PHP.

Comment: OK, so there's nothing wrong about calculating this on server-side. Is there?

Comment: Nop server side is ok, i want show every data fom DB in export plugin, and  show on graph the calculate percent.